# How to pass variables from extended class to another in Object-Oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have been trying to change my functions that heavily use global variables into classes. I got into a problem of accessing the variable `$totalRows` in class `Sister`, which is a total row count fetched from mysql and passed into the extended class `Brother`.

Just a pseudo code to get the point across. The real situation is more complicated and prevents me from putting all these into one big class:

```
class Mother{

  public function __construct($itemPerPage){

     $this->itemPerPage = $itemPerPage;
  }
}

class Brother extends Mother{

    public function __construct($totalRows){

       $this->totalRows = $totalRows;

    }
}

class Sister extends Mother{

    public function renderPager(){

       $totalRows = $this->totalRows;

       $itemPerPage = $this->itemPerPage;

       $totalPages = ceil($totalRows/$itemPerPage);

    }
}
```

The `$totalRows` can't be read in `Sister` because it is not in the main class `Mother`. Should I just simply pass the  `$totalRows` again in a __construct function in `Sister`? Is there another way to pass `$totalRows` from `Brother` to `Sister`?

Comment: The point of using oop is to reuse your variables/function from base classes in your extended classes. So if you need totalRows in Sister and Brother you should move your totalRows to Mother. If this is what you want...

Comment: Yes, you can pass it: `$sis->totalRows = $bro->totalRows;`. But really without any context or knowing what you want to do, it's not possible to give a proper answer.

Comment: I think you are talking about classes as if they were objects.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in the design and should be solved otherwise. What are you trying to achieve (not how)?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Brother extends Mother{
  protected $totalRows;
    public function __construct($totalRows){

       $this->totalRows = $totalRows;

    }
}
```

Working ?

Answer (score 0):

init Brother class before Sister class. Define totalRows inside Mother class and you should be fine. For example define totalRows array and use it like that:

```
class Mother{
    public $totalRows = array();
  public function __construct($itemPerPage){

     $this->itemPerPage = $itemPerPage;
  }
}

class Brother extends Mother{

    public function __construct($totalRows){

       $this->totalRows['brother'] = $totalRows;

    }
}
```

But remember, if You dont init Mother class, use parent::__construct inside your Brother construction. Otherwise Mother constructor will be overrided